# Mocking Module methods

Tags: python-3.x, django, mocking, python-unittest, patch

I have a situation which i could not find on stack-overflow:

some_module.py:

```
class SomeModule():
   def a(): pass
   def b(): pass
   def c(): pass

   @classmethod
   def bring_them_altogether(cls):
      cls.a()
      cls.b()
      cls.c()
```

I am writing a unittest and would like to test the method `bring_them_altogether()` by determining that methods a(), b() & c() are all called once.

In my testcase i have this:

test.py:

```
@patch('<...>.some_module.SomeModule', autospec=True)
def test_bring_them_altogether(self, mock_class):
   mock_class.bring_them_altogether()
   self.assertTrue(mock_class.called)  # Returns me False
```

I want to know how to write a proper test case for bring_them_altogether() as i seem to be having some issues getting the output i want.

On that note, I want to know how to determine that a mocked-method has been called X - number of times.

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Well you've mocked the entire class under test, so the real `bring_them_altogether` would never be called. You should just mock a, b, c in that class and then call bring_them_altogether; then you can use [`assert_has_calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls).

Comment: Also, don't call a class a module; they are different things.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) to patch `a`, `b`, `c` methods of `SomeModule` class. Check if they are called or not after executing the `bring_them_altogether` method.

E.g.

`some_module.py`:

```py
class SomeModule():
    def a(): pass
    def b(): pass
    def c(): pass

    @classmethod
    def bring_them_altogether(cls):
        cls.a()
        cls.b()
        cls.c()
```

`test_some_module.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from some_module import SomeModule


class TestSomeModule(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch.object(SomeModule, 'c')
    @patch.object(SomeModule, 'b')
    @patch.object(SomeModule, 'a')
    def test_bring_them_altogether(self, mock_a, mock_b, mock_c):
        SomeModule.bring_them_altogether()
        mock_a.assert_called_once()
        mock_b.assert_called_once()
        mock_c.assert_called_once()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/58950420/some_module.py            8      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/58950420/test_some_module.py      13      0   100%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                               21      0   100%
```